# SQLite query from multiple tables using SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 tables in my database, for example: `Table1: id (PK), data1` and `Table2: id (PK), id_table1 (FK), data2`. How can I make a query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id_table1 
GROUP BY Table1.data1
```

I'm using `SQLiteDatabase` and its `query()` method.

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, new String[] {"Table1","Table2"}, 
new String[] {"Table1.id","data1", "Table2.id", "id_table1", "data2"},
"Table1.id=Table2.id_table1", null, "Table1.data1", null,null,null);
```

But there's a problem with the second arg - it's only possible to use String, not String[] (like `new String[] {"Table1","Table2}`). What should I do to make a query from multiple tables in that way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 " +
                             "WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id_table1 " +
                             "GROUP BY Table1.data1", null);
```

Comment: @Graham how to pass id in this

Answer (score 14):

So when you need to `JOIN` Tables, you have to use `rawQuery` instead of `query`.
So your statement

```
String SELECT_QUERY = SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.data1;
```

I recommend to you use `JOIN` because it more faster and safer then your approach. So then your `rawQuery` method can looks like this:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY, null);
```

Have look at 
[rawQuery in SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Regards