# LoaderManager/CursorLoader for several cursors?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I have two SQLite tables:
**Service:** sid (prim.key), workDesc, title
**ServiceInstance:** ssid (prim.key), sid(foreign key), date, workComment, odometer

Today I'm using a CustomAdapter extending SimpleCursorAdapter to feed a ListView with data from these tables. But since this method is deprecated, I want refactor the code using LoaderManager/CursorLoader instead.

Now, my confusion is that in the ListView, I want to show the date from the ServiceInstance table and the title from the Service table. Like:
2013-06-05 Regular service

How can I do that? Since now when I'm using my extended SimpleCursorAdapter-class, I'm sending a cursor to the constructor. But in this case when I have changed the database structure a bit, I need to show data from two different cursors (Service and ServiceInstance).

I have googled and read a couple of tutorials but not found any similar case. But here, http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-database-content-provider.html

Where they declare the string array columns (step 6, MainActivity.java:58), can I just add the column names (date and title) even though they exist in different tables?

Another question, I don't plan to provide these data to other apps, so is it a meaning to create a ContentProvider anyway?

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't be necessary to bind to two different cursors in your case (and i wouldn't recommend it, since you would have to write your own adapter in that case).
Try to query across your tables instead, check this for a starting point:

- [SQLite query from multiple tables using SQLiteDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029538/sqlite-query-from-multiple-tables-using-sqlitedatabase)
- [how to use join query in CursorLoader when its constructor does not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090695/how-to-use-join-query-in-cursorloader-when-its-constructor-does-not-support-it)

For your second question, if you don't want to expose your ContentProvider to other applications set:

```
<provider
    ....
    android:exported="false">
</provider>
```

in your manifest

Comment: Regarding my second question, I wonder what I should pass to the CursorLoader constructor, since it requires a URI as second argument?

Comment: The Uri as defined in your content provider, let me know if you need an example (I'm on holidays and will be back at a computer next week).

Comment: I know that, but I don't plan to provide these data to other apps, so is it possible to not use a ContentProvider? Or is it better to create one anyway?

Comment: i would create one, and just set the android:exported="false", it's convenient to use once setup, you could use a CursorLoader without a content provider, but it requires some workarounds. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Workarounds are not something I'm striving for, so I will create one and not export it. Just need to find a good example, do you have one available?

Comment: i think this one is pretty good, but very long also
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html